# How to verify lets encrypt certs with server? - OSCP error linux Strongswan

Tags: linux, vpn, encryption, ipsec, strongswan

### Goal

I am attempting to build an IKEv2 VPN using the strongswan IPSEC implementation with Let's Encrypt certificates and RSA authentication. I successfully built it in the legacy ipsec.conf format, but the new swanctl.conf format has proved itself more difficult for me.

I believe the problem is my VPN will reach out to let's Encrypt servers to validate the certificate. The VPN successfully authenticates the client, but the client will not accept the tunnel because the cert is not deemed valid.

iOS Client Console Log Error https://i.stack.imgur.com/H57nO.png

### Syslog on daemon startup

https://pastebin.com/SktVvJUs

### Syslog on client attempting to connect:

https://pastebin.com/hTs01WXC

Note that the server authenticates the client

### swanctl.conf

```
connections {

ikev2-pubkey {
    version = 2
    proposals = aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes256- 
    sha256-modp2048,default
    rekey_time = 0s
    pools = primary-pool-ipv4, primary-pool-ipv6
    fragmentation = yes
    dpd_delay = 30s
    send_cert=always
    local-1 {
        auth = pubkey
        certs = <path>fullchain.pem
        id = <my_id>
    }
    remote-1 {
        # defaults are fine
        auth = pubkey
    }
    children {
        ikev2-pubkey {
            local_ts = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
            rekey_time = 0s
            dpd_action = clear
            esp_proposals = aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1,default
        }
    }
 }
```

Can you help me?

**Edit 1**

The Linux box console used to say "error no suitable catcher found". So I then installed curl as a plugin and recompiled from source. That error has gone away but this error persists.

**Edit 2**
Adding server configuration, syslog for daemon startup and attempting to tunnel

Comment: Looks like you may not be sending the entire certificate chain. Let’s Encrypt needs an intermediate root certificate to link to "DST Root CA X3".

Comment: Okay, so, on my client I can see: `sending cert request for "O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3"`and `sending cert request for "C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1"`. Are these certificates available for the IKE daemon to send?

Comment: In addition to what @DanielB said, you might not be sending any certificates at all. The default is to send them only if the client sent a certificate request. To force it, configure `send_cert = always` in your connection.

Comment: @DanielB Are you using the ipsec.conf or swanctl.conf? Because I've seen similar outputs on the ipsec.conf but not on the swanctl.conf daemon. 

But yes these certificates are available for use. Let me verify I am using the correct one.

Comment: @ecdsa The client is receiving the cert, that is why this error is produced. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: It might not receive _all_ the certs, make sure the intermediate CA certificate is loaded and sent (as @DanielB already said). Those log messages he posted have nothing to do with the configuration backend that's used.

Comment: @ecdsa (I am appreciative of your help, hope my comment did not come across as condescending) I did verify that that cert the client is using is the full-chain, and I set the `send_cert = always` as you said. Still unable to connect.

Comment: @DanielB I believe the certs are available to the IKE daemon, does it show in the syslog that I added?

Comment: According to your log, the intermediate CA certificate is not loaded, so it can't be sent (put a symlink to Let's Encrypt's current `chain.pem` in `/etc/swanctl/x509ca` to load it). However, the client apparently aborts before any IKE_AUTH messages are exchanged. Actually, the client even says so: `Failed to create IKE Auth packet`. How did you configure it? If you used a profile and set `ServerCertificateIssuerCommonName`, you can't use the intermediate CA certificate's CN unless you install that manually on the client (only the root CA cert with CN `DST Root CA X3` will already be there).